# How to validate_uniquness_of for a specific user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

`validate_uniquness_of` does not allow me to see if this is Object is unique to a specific user because I can not call current_user from the model..

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scope your validation against the user_id.

```
class Child < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user

  validate_uniqueness_of :whatever, :scope => :user_id

end
```

Comment: Horse? I won't ask. No problem.